# Varying, exclusive limits on concurrency in GitLab runner

Tags: gitlab, concurrency, gitlab-runner

I have a Linux server used as a GitLab runner. I'd like the server to be usable for two different purposes simultaneously:

1. For build jobs, unit tests, etc. (things that aren't timing sensitive) many jobs can be run concurrently to take advantage of the memory availability of the system and make better use of the CPU while some jobs are doing I/O-bound activities like downloading dependencies.
2. When a timing-sensitive job (a performance test) is being run, no other build jobs etc. should be running because if they're competing for system resources the test results won't be comparable between runs.

Is there a way to set up a GitLab runner `config.toml` in a way that jobs of type `1` can run concurrently but the jobs of type `2` are guaranteed to be run without any other jobs going on at the same time?